# What are the technical details of travelling to Cuba (in 2016)

Tags: visas, us-citizens, cuba, german-citizens

[There are multiple questions and answers here on SE about travel to Cuba, but they are all written *before the opening* - I am asking about late 2016]

I am considering travelling to Cuba for educational purposes, and I have identified flights and hotels, etc. My question is about the technicalities:

If you fly *from a non-US airport* (for example, Mexico City) to Havana/Cuba, what paperwork do you have to have with you when you arrive (as a US citizen or German citizen, either way, because we have both in the group)?

I assume a passport, of course, and better bring some cash, but *what do you need outside of this*?

Do you need any health insurance documentation, and how would that look? Any upfront arranged visa or other paperwork? Or can you just walk from the plane, pay whatever fees, and be fine?

There are many sources on the web, I spend days reading around; but most are obsolete, and many are contradicting. I'd prefer to hear from someone who *did it*, maybe in the last three months, in the current political situation:

**What was really needed when you arrived?** which sheets of paper, and how did you get them?

Comment: @pnuts presumably the rapprochement between the US and Cuba. Commercial flights between the two countries have recently resumed, for example.

Comment: @pnuts I don't know whether Cuba did change any regulations, but it certainly seems like they might have, especially any regulations concerning US citizen visitors.

Comment: Sorry I was not online the last hour. Yes, I mean the opening for US citizens which has already resulted in an explosion of travel; and some sources claimed is was 'easier than ever' to enter the country, without specifying detail. I was really hoping for someone who has personal experience from the last months.

Comment: @Aganju: I can add that in January 2016, for French citizens, we had to get a visa from the Embassy in France before traveling. We also read about health insurance but never been asked to provide documents about that (we were covered by our credit card contract and brought a document but was useless in our case)

Comment: Please split this into separate questions - as per the [help], and note that while there are other questions covering Cuba, the 'opening' only really applies to US citizens (eg I went there over a year ago as a NZ citizen).